# Pygame Problem with Scoring/ Eating An Apple To Gain Points

Tags: python, pygame, new-operator

So basically I was trying to make a basic scoring system and apple that I can eat to gain points but this keeps happening --- https://gyazo.com/89ec9b6d8cfd27cf4bb85ceb5738ca9b it wont let me eat the apples and it keeps flicking on my screen please help I have marked where the scoring and and everything is on the code

```
import pygame
import time
import random
pygame.init()


window = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("I am a hacker")


# player class
class players(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.isJump = False
        self.JumpCount = 10
        self.fall = 0
        self.speed = 5

# enemy class
class enemys(object):
    def __init__(self,cordx,cordy,heights,widths):
        self.cordx = cordx
        self.cordy = cordy
        self.heights = heights
        self.widths = widths


# color blue for player
blue = (32,207,173)

red = (255,0,0)

orange = (207,135,32)


# FPS
FPS = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

display_width = 50
display_height = 50
font_style = pygame.font.SysFont("bahnschrift", 25)
score_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 35)


# -----------------------------------------------------
# scoring and apple varabiles etc
snake_block = 10
snake_speed = 15 
def Your_score(score):
    value = score_font.render("Your Score: " + str(score), True, red)
    window.blit(value, [0, 0])



def our_snake(snake_block, snake_list):
    for x in snake_list:
        pygame.draw.rect(window, red, [x[0], x[1], snake_block, snake_block])


def message(msg, color):
    mesg = font_style.render(msg, True, color)
    window.blit(mesg, [500 / 6, 500 / 3])


game_over = False
game_close = False

x1 = 500 / 2
y1 = 500 / 2

x1_change = 0
y1_change = 0

snake_List = []
Length_of_snake = 1

foodx = round(random.randrange(0, 500 - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0
foody = round(random.randrange(0, 500 - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


# Main Loop
playerman = players(50,390,50,50)
enemyman = enemys(190,390,150,10)
runninggame = True
while runninggame:

    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            runninggame = False
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Scoring and Apple System
    if x1 >= 500 or x1 < 0 or y1 >= 500 or y1 < 0:
            game_close = True
            x1 += x1_change
            y1 += y1_change
            window.fill(red)
    pygame.draw.rect(window, red, [foodx, foody, snake_block, snake_block])
    snake_Head = []
    snake_Head.append(x1)
    snake_Head.append(y1)
    snake_List.append(snake_Head)
    if len(snake_List) > Length_of_snake:
        del snake_List[0]
        for x in snake_List[:-1]:
            if x == snake_Head:
                game_close = True

        our_snake(snake_block, snake_List)
        Your_score(Length_of_snake - 1)

        pygame.display.update()

        if x1 == foodx and y1 == foody:
            foodx = round(random.randrange(0, 500 - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0
            foody = round(random.randrange(0, 500 - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0
            Length_of_snake += 1
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------




    window.fill((0,0,0))
    player = pygame.draw.rect(window,(blue),(playerman.x,playerman.y,playerman.height,playerman.width))
    enemy = pygame.draw.rect(window,(orange),(enemyman.cordx,enemyman.cordy,enemyman.heights,enemyman.widths))

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and playerman.x > playerman.speed:
        playerman.x -= playerman.speed
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and playerman.x < 500 - playerman.width - playerman.speed:
        playerman.x += playerman.speed

    if not playerman.isJump:

        playerman.y += playerman.fall
        playerman.fall += 1
# ----------------------------------------------------- # enem1 collisio
# both of my 2 enemy squares collisions push me back when ever I Jump on the top of them on there sides but when I jump on the middle of of both of them it seems to work if I just want it so when I jump on both of my squares I just don't get pushed back 
        player.topleft = (playerman.x, playerman.y)
        collide = False
        playerman.isJump = False
        if player.colliderect(enemy):
            collide = True
            playerman.isJump = False
            playerman.y = enemy.top - player.height
            if player.right > enemy.left and  player.left < enemy.left - player.width:
                playerman.x = enemy.left - player.width
            if player.left < enemy.right and  player.right > enemy.right + player.width:
                playerman.x = enemy.right



        if player.bottom >= 500:
            collide = True
            playerman.isJump = False
            playerman.JumpCount = 10
            playerman.y = 500 - player.height

        if collide:
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                playerman.isJump = True
            playerman.fall = 0

    else:
        if playerman.JumpCount > 0:
            playerman.y -= (playerman.JumpCount*abs(playerman.JumpCount)) * 0.5
            playerman.JumpCount -= 1
        else:
            playerman.JumpCount = 10
            playerman.isJump = False







    pygame.display.update()


pygame.quit()
``
```

Comment: You might consider constructing an MRE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to better address these two problems. Try to simplify your code as much as possible while still reproducing either bug.

Answer (score 1):

Your program is kinda a mess. You have a snake and food, but the snake doesn't move to get the food, that is the first problem. you also say apples, but there is only one apple, the other one is your snake. But you also have a player and enemies and the player is not a snake, so not sure what the intention is here so not quite sure how to help without more information

But, to fix the flickering, you have `pygame.display.update()` 2 times, with a `window.fill((0,0,0))` in between them, so what was happening is your updating the screen with the apple, then clearing the screen, then updating it again.

To fix:

delete the `pygame.display.update()` in

```
if len(snake_List) > Length_of_snake:
        ...

        pygame.display.update() #delete

        if x1 == foodx and y1 == foody:
            ...
```

and move the `window.fill((0,0,0))` to the first line in the loop

```
runninggame = True
while runninggame:

    window.fill((0,0,0))
    ...
```

Comment: I am sorry man I know its a mess but I am beginner programmer and I am trying to make a platformer game with a simple object that I will eat and gain points on my screen so sorry

Comment: @HabibIsmail Don't be sorry, we all got to start somewhere, you should see how horrible my code is when i tried to make a text editor with pygame. But you do basically have the snake game in your program. did you copy and paste snake game for the food and not want the snake game? You check for collision with food for snake but the snake only moves with `x1_change` that is always 0. you need to change it to the player over the food, not snake